# Turning on the flashlight on Lumia 1520 on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I want to turn on the flashlight on my Lumia 1520. I try this code but it doesn't work:

```
if (captureManager.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Supported)
        {
            var videoEncodingProperties = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Vga);
            StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
            StorageFile videoStorageFile;               
            videoStorageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("tempVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            Capture.Source = captureManager;
            await captureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(videoEncodingProperties, videoStorageFile);
            captureManager.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = true;
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            }
            captureManager.VideoDeviceController.TorchControl.Enabled = false;
            captureManager.Dispose();
        }
```

I tried this post [Toggle flashlight in Windows Phone 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847510/toggle-flashlight-in-windows-phone-8-1) but it not help.
FlashControl and TorchControl supported. It no error and no light.

Comment: "does not work" is not enough information to see why this post is not duplicate of many existing once. If linked post did not provide an answer - make sure to clearly explain what options you've tried (like turning on flash as suggested in duplicate) and how they did not work (i.e. feature not supported, wrong camera selected, ...).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: forgive me. I have tried many different post like this to make this code. I also tried flashlight app in store and  it work fine.

Comment: Have you tried [starting preview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31698061/2681948)?

Comment: @Romasz: my app is wp8.1 runtime and this for wp8.1 silverlight :)

Comment: @Rain Both are using the same API in this case. It's just shoot in the dark - it may be worth to try, I'm not sure if that would help.

Comment: @Romasz: thank you. I had solved my problem. just add await captureManager.StartPreviewAsync(); before             videoStorageFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync("tempVideo.mp4", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName); thank all again!

Comment: @Rain I've reopened your post as you've added missing details. You can post answer her too if you want to - thanks for posting answer to the other one.